# 12.04 User-account not listed

Tags: 12.04, login, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.04 User Accounts not listed in System Settings User Accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147536/12-04-user-accounts-not-listed-in-system-settings-user-accounts)

After incremental updates from 10.10, to 12.04, go back to gnome rather than Unity, and some troubleshooting, I can use my 12.04, but I need to use gdm to "gui"-log into my session (no problem to login via tty).
In 11.10, lightdm didn't show my user, but I could specify it and still log in.
In 12.04, I had no possibility in lightdm to specify my user.
So I found a temp workaround: use gdm as default-display-manager and so I can specify my account to log into Ubuntu.
When in System settings/System/User Accounts, my user is not listed (user-id = 601)
How could I troubleshoot this ? the goal is to get my account listed in the "gui" list of user accounts, and so go forward to lightdm.
Thanks for tips.

Comment: Which architecture do you run Ubuntu on? This might be the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/952909?comments=all which affects accountsservice on some architectures like ARM (e.g., on Toshiba AC100) or PPC. It has already been fixed in the original Debian packages, but not yet in Ubuntu's packages AFAIK.