# User Accounts not listed in System Settings User Accounts

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen, users, ppc

I'm running 12.04 on PPC (IMAC G5) - but have a problem with creating/editing user accounts with the System Preferences User Accounts tool.   All updates have been downloaded and installed.

When I run the tool my account appears under the Other Accounts line and I do not see any other accounts - I can unlock and add an account, though this does not appear in the list.  However the accounts are created in /etc/passwd.

LightDM only displays the last user account created, and after login by command line and enabling the account/setting a password it is possible to login to LightDM as this user.

I have added the old gnome users.admin package which does allow me to see all users on the system, but accounts still do not show up in LightDM.

lightdm.conf and users.conf are set correctly, with minimum UID set to 1000.   However I understand that these should be ignored with requests handled by accounts-daemon.

The accountsservice appears to be started/running - though I am not sure how or where to debug this.

I am not using any prescribed service account names - makes no difference if users are administrators or standard accounts.   I have searched the forums and found only one unanswered post that matches - so at least not totally alone!

If any one can assist or point out the error of my ways it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/952909?comments=all which affects accountsservice from Ubuntu 12.04 on some architectures like ARM (e.g., on Toshiba AC100) and PPC? Read there for the reason of this bug.

As of the end of July 2012, there is a fix in the `precise-proposed` repository -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/accountsservice/+bug/952909/comments/13.

(Before that, there was no fix for this bug in Ubuntu's packages (I've checked for my case -- ARM), but this bug has been fixed in the original Debian package. Although, I'm not sure the Debian package is completely compatible with Ubuntu (you can read about my experience of installing it in a comment there: "user accounts" settings didn't work for me after the installation), but at least the login screen should work  fine (i.e., list all the users) after installing the package from Debian.)

Comment: Can you provide SSH access to a PPC? Launchpad does not support building for PowerPC, and this requires a PowerPC host environment. Emulation would be too slow.

Comment: @izx Are you sure there's no `.deb` package for PPC already (from Debian)? That would most likely work fine. Also, why is cross-compilation out of the question?

Comment: @izx Sorry, unfortunately, at that time I didn't have a system with one of the affected architectures. But fortunately, there is a package with a fix in precise-proposed now.

Comment: @imz: No problem, glad to know there's a solution :)

Comment: @Eliah But the package for Debian didn't fit well into Ubuntu, as I wrote in my comments: the login screen was correct with it, but the accounts settings menu in Ubuntu didn't work. So one would wish a native Ubuntu's package.